# apply and updating arguments in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a question regarding R `apply` (and all its variants). Is there a way to update the arguments of the function while `apply` is working?

For example, I have a function `NextSol(Prev_Sol)` that generates a new solution from `Prev_Sol`, compares it with the original one in some way and then returns either the original or the new, depending on the result of the comparison. I need to save all the solutions returned. Currently, I am doing this:

```
for( i in 2:N ) {
  Results[[i]] <- NextSol(Results[[i-1]])
}
```

But maybe there is a (faster) way to do it using `apply`? I have seen also that `Reduce` could help but I have no idea of how can I use it. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Generally the for-loop is the way to go for these types of processes that build on previous iterations. The `apply` family are still loops, they're just doing things a little differently under the hood that make tasks like yours more difficult than just doing calling a loop directly.

Comment: AFAIK, `apply` and it's variants are useful only in non-path dependent loops/iterations. For path-dependent loops `apply` won't give any performance benefit.

Comment: Well that was fast! Thanks very much, if any of you want to write the answer I will accept it and also my defeat to the `for` loop :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thomas said, the for loop is the standard way of looping when one iteration depends on a previous one.  (Just make sure that you correctly handle the case of `N = 1` in your code.)

An alternative is to use the `Reduce` function.  This example is adapted from the one on the `?Reduce` help page.

```
NextSol <- function(x) x + 1 #Or whatever you want

Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)
Reduce(Funcall, rep.int(list(NextSol), 5), 0, right = TRUE)
## [1] 5
```

It's unlikely that this will be much faster, and it's arguably harder to read, so you may well decide to stick with a for loop.

---

Well, I suppose we can make it easier to read by wrapping it in an `Iterate` function.

```
Iterate <- function(f, init, n)
{
  Reduce(
    function(f, ...) f(...), 
    rep.int(list(f), n), 
    init, 
    right = TRUE
  )
}

Iterate(NextSol, 0, 5) #same as before
```

Comment: Understood. I think that for now I will stay with the `for` and will check whether `Reduce` makes it much faster. Thank you very much!